# What is the purpose of List<?> if one can only insert a null value?

Tags: java, generics, unbounded-wildcard

Based on the information provided in the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html), it says that:

> It's important to note that `List<Object>` and `List<?>` are not the same. You can insert an Object, or any subtype of Object, into a `List<Object>`. But you can only insert null into a `List<?>`.

What is the use of using `List<?>` when only `null` can be inserted?

For example,

`methodOne(ArrayList<?> l):` We can use this method for `ArrayList` of any type but within the method we can’t add anything to the List except `null`.

```
l.add(null);//(valid)
l.add("A");//(invalid)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use the unbounded wildcards when the list (or the collection) is of *unknown types*.

Like the tutorial says, it's used when you want to get information about some list, like printing its content, but you *don't know* what type it might be containing:

```
public static void printList(List<?> list) {
    for (Object elem: list)
        System.out.print(elem + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

You shouldn't use it when you want to insert values to the list, since the only value allowed is `null`, because you don't know what values it contains..

Answer (score 5):

You can **get** elements from your list.

`List<?>` is usually used as a type for a list of unknown-typed objects returned by a method or so, where you read elements from, rather than adding them.

Answer (score 1):

`List<?>` is quite different. If we try and add objects into a `List<?>`, even if the object is of type `Object`, we can't do it. It says,

> `add(capture<?>)` in `java.util.List` cannot be applied to `(java.lang.Object)`

Now that might seem a bit restrictive. If you can't have any values being passed as parameters, which is what I mean when I say put into a list, then, what can you do with it?

Well, let's see why that restriction exists. To begin with, we know that arrays are covariant. So what that means is we could take an array of Strings and put that into an Object Array.

[image: Array of Strings to Object]

So here, if we take that first object and we assign it to a random String, everything will be fine. And if we assign it to a new Object, if we add that in, then we will get an ArrayStoreException

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Object
```

because of the unsafety of covariant arrays.

Well, in the case of `List<?>`,  what the Java compiler is trying to do for us by banning us from adding values into a `List<?>` or a `List<? extends Object>` is put us into a position where this type can only be safely used. And in fact, the only value that you are allowed to put into a `List<?>` is the `null` value because `null` can be coerced into any type.